# How can I configure Gmail with Oracle Apex using stunnel (application express) 5.0.3

Tags: oracle, email, gmail, oracle-apex, stunnel

How can I setup Oracle Apex (application express) to send emails through my Gmail account without using my own SMTP ?

Comment: Please see [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320607/266304). Self-answering is fine, but you still need a good question and a separate answer. In this case a question like 'How to configure Gmail...' would be too broad and off-topic anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

**Background :**

- Apex 5.0.3 is installed with Oracle XE 11.2 installed on **Centos**
  (linux) 6.x
- SMTP is not required to be enabled on centos. We will use gmail one
  directly.
- Solution is based on **windows** implementation published by : HÅVARD KRISTIANSEN at
  : 
  http://monkeyonoracle.blogspot.com/2009/11/plsql-and-gmail-or-utlsmtp-with-ssl.html
- Will use stunnel to communicate with gmail directly.
- Apex / Oracle XE installation instructions are not included.

**Installation (written out of my head) :**

1.Install stunnel as root :

```
yum install stunnel -y
```

2.create a conf file for stunnel using nano or vi (to install nano : yum install nano -y )

```
nano /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
```

3.Enter the following to new stunnel.conf created:

```
; Use it for client mode
client = yes

[ssmtp]
accept  = 1925
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
```

4.restart stunnel using whatever method, e.g kill -9 and start using the following command :

```
/usr/bin/stunnel
```

5.Log in to apex as admin : http://yourhost:port/ords/apex_admin

```
Go to : Manage instance -> instance settings.
```

6.Put the following settings :

```
SMTP Host Address : 127.0.0.1 (or your local)
SMTP Host Port : 1925 (as u can see in stunnel.conf above).
SMTP Authentication Username : your gmail username : etai.guday (WITHOUT @gmail.com)
SMTP Authentication Password : gmail password
Use SSL/TLS : NO
Default Email From Address : etai.guday@gmail.com (including @gmail.com)
```

7.Due to gmail restrictions YOU MUST enable : https://g.co/allowaccess to use the above method (with relevant gmail account).

8.Enable Oracle DB ACL by using example bellow

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ieaawy5gme9a50/email_configuration_acl_for_apex.txt?dl=0
```

All above should work :-) didn't have time to test it further or refer to security issues etc